# In bash, when creating Variables. When to export and when not to export?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, command-line-interface

From what I've read, is it correct to assume that the only thing export does is make the variable visible to child processes?

What would be a scenario where you would want to make a variable only visible to the scope it was initialized in, and what would be a scenario in which you would want a variable available to all child scopes?

Comment: Scope != process. A shell variable is available to any child scopes within the same process without exporting it.

Comment: @chepner   Gotcha.  So I guess how does export come into play then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you only need to export a variable that *another* process will look for in its environment. How do you know which variables those are? You have to read their documentation.

Whether or not a variable is marked for export makes *no* difference to the current shell.

Let's construct a demonstration.

```
$ printf 'echo "foo=$foo"\n' > script
$ bash script
foo=
$ foo=3
$ bash script
foo=
$ export foo
bash script
foo=3
```

The first time *and* second time you run `script`, `foo` is undefined in its environment because its parent process (the current shell) did not export `foo`. The third time it is called, the parent adds `foo` to the script's initial environment because `foo` was exported.

---

In response to your comment, the term "environment" has a very precise meaning here. *All* processes, not just shells, receive an array of strings from its parent on startup, referred to as its environment. There are no particular semantics associated with these strings; it's up to the receiving program how to interpret them.

The shell, for example, ignores strings in its environment that do not have the form `name=value`, where `name` is a valid shell identifier. For each such string, the shell defines a shell variable with the given name and value, and marks its export attribute. This is what we mean by an environment variable. You can also "promote" a regular shell variable at any time to an environment variable using the `export` command, but this doesn't affect the meaning of the variable in the current process.

When any process creates a new process, a copy of its environment is given to the new process. The shell additionally creates `name=value` strings to pass on from each of its environment variables.

Comment: Thanks!  This is starting to make more sense.  I'm still having a hard time grasping the difference between a shell and an environment.  When I open terminal on osx, am I opening a new environment?

Comment: I would not say "another program", because only child processes can have access to exported variables, while arbitrary other programs certainly don´t.

Comment: @Harald Thanks. I caught myself typing "program" many times where I meant to say "process"; that one slipped by.